# PHP ¿Por que sigue recargando la pagina?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Hice un formulario en PHP y le incluí AJAX para que no recargue la pagina cada vez que lo ejecuto. Sin embargo, sigue recargando la pagina. El script funciona perfecto porque me devuelve lo que quiero, pero no entiendo por qué la pagina sigue recargándose. Alguien sabría decirme?

**Formulario**

```
                <form action="" method="post" onsubmit="enviar();">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id"
                        value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($producto['ID'], COD,KEY)?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="nombre" id="nombre"
                        value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($producto['Nombre'], COD,KEY)?>">
                    <input type="hidden" name="precio" id="precio"
                        value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($producto['Precio'], COD,KEY) ?>">
                    <input type="number" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" value="1" min="1" max="20">

                    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="btnAccion" value="Agregar" type="submit">Agregar al
                        carrito</button>

                </form>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
var dataen = "nombre=" + nombre + "&id=" + id;

function enviar() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'test.php',
        data: dataen,
        success: function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
        }
    });
    return false;
}
</script>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php 

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];

    echo "Tu id es $id, el nombre del producto es $nombre";

?>
```

Comment: No debes usar `submit` solo un botón con un `id` y utilizar la función `click` de ese elemento en el script.

Comment: Probé dejando: ```<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="enviar();">``` nada mas, pero sigue recargándose igual

Comment: Gracias!! era eso, tenia que agregar  ```event.preventDefault();```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que hacer esto:

En el formulario pasas el evento a la función en el onsubmit de esta manera:

```
<form action="" method="post" onsubmit="enviar(event);">
```

Luego en la funcion detienes el recargado de la página de esta manera:

```
function enviar(event) {
event.preventDefault();
...
}
```